# the change in the windows service's name does not take effect

Tags: windows-services, multiple-instances, installutil

This is essentially a follow up of the following question:

[How to increase/decrease the number of instances of a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242568/how-to-increase-decrease-the-number-of-instances-of-a-windows-service)

I've tried the following:

```
installutil /instance_name=instance1 mysvc.exe
```

The above command does the job of installing the service; and you can see the service listed in the mmc console (services.msc) as "instance1". But while debugging I've noticed that the `ServiceName` property is showing the value that I set in the designer at design time.

I was expecting it to show "instance1". How to correctly resolve this problem?

Comment: The service name is only used by `installutil` to determine the name for the system if you don't pass it on the command line. The service itself won't "pull" the service name from the Registry or something.

Comment: I don't know but it could be the name of the service inside .csproj file dictating the name that appears inside services sections.